# Returning object with EJB 3

Tags: java, ejb, javabeans, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to work with the EJB 3, but I'm missing something. 
Initially I created a stateless bean that I called through the controller of the mvc.
The bean contained a method that returned a String.

Now, I'm wiling to go to the next level, namely I'm trying to create a bean that returns an object instead of a string.

Persona.java

```
package com.pojo;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Persona implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String nome;
    int eta;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public int getEta() {
        return eta;
    }
    public void setEta(int eta) {
        this.eta = eta;
    }
}
```

RitornaPersonaRemote.java

```
package com.demo.view;

import com.pojo.Persona;

public interface RitornaPersonaRemote {
    public Persona getPersona();
}
```

RitornaPersona.java

```
package com.demo;

import com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote;

@Stateless
@Remote(RitornaPersonaRemote.class)
public class RitornaPersona implements RitornaPersonaRemote {

    public Persona getPersona(){
        Persona p = new Persona();
        p.setEta(18);
        p.setNome("tizio");
        return p;
    }
}
```

Client side
My_controller.java

```
package controller;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote;


@Controller
public class My_Controller {

    @EJB
    private RitornaPersonaRemote rp;

    @RequestMapping("testpage")
    public ModelAndView mostraPagina(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("testpage");
        model.addObject("hello", "nome --> " + persona.getPersona().getNome());
        return model;
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

        <!-- enable autowire -->
        <context:annotation-config/>
        <context:spring-configured/>

  <jee:local-slsb id="RitornaPersona" 
  jndi-name="java:app/RitornaPersonaSenzaClient/RitornaPersona!com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote"
  business-interface="com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote" />
</beans>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
   <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
      <jee:jndi-lookup id="RitornaPersonaSenzaClient" jndi-name="com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="alwaysUseJndiLookup" value="true" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>RitornaPersonaWeb</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <display-name>spring</display-name>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


  <ejb-ref>
    <description>
    </description>
    <ejb-ref-name>RitornaPersonaSenzaClient</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <home></home>
    <remote>com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote</remote>
    <ejb-link>RitornaPersona</ejb-link>
  </ejb-ref>
</web-app>
```

The errors that I'm getting are pasted here:
http://justpaste.it/gfs3

Please, can someone tell me were are my mistakes? 
I looked on lots of guide, but I lost the path.

Comment: From the exception trace:The short-form default binding 'com.demo.view.RitornaPersonaRemote' is ambiguous because multiple beans implement the interface : [RitornaPersonaSenzaClientEAR#RitornaPersonaSenzaClient.jar#RitornaPersona

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, but how can I solve the error. I don't understand because I delete the code lines in the xml, cleaned the project, but the results were the same

Comment: I'm not sure, try to use the @remote annotation in the interface instead of the bean.Also, I have doubts about if it is necessary to use the element ejb-link.

Comment: I've added @Remote in the interface and deleted the ejb-link line, but unfortunately nothing have changed.